# Java: How can I dynamically create an array of a specified type based on the type of an object?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to take a passed List that I know is homogeneous and from it create an array of the same type as the elements within it.

Something like...

```
List<Object> lst = new ArrayList<Object>;

lst.add(new Integer(3));

/// somewhere else ...

assert(my_array instanceof Integer[]);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The conversion would happen runtime, while the type is lost at compile time. So you should do something like:

```
public <T> T[] toArray(List<T> list) {
    Class clazz = list.get(0).getClass(); // check for size and null before
    T[] array = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());
    return list.toArray(array);
}
```

But beware that the 3rd line above may throw an exception - it's not typesafe.

Comment: +1: It's fine as long as the type of the first element of the list is the same as or a superclass of the type of all the other list elements. That's a very sneaky assumption, but may well work given the constraints in the question.

Comment: indeed. the OP said "that I know is homogeneous", but that's something that shouldn't be "extralinguistic".

Comment: Fine for a `List<String>`.  Completely useless for a `List<Shape>`

Comment: @finnw: That's why I made my comment about it being a sneaky assumption. The real problem is that the generic type is erased after compilation – there's just no way to get it at runtime – so you have to guess what the type of the array needs to be. Bozho's code does about the best you can do with sane amounts of effort; going through the list and working out the common supertype of all the elements would be safer, but it's stupidly awkward and *in the case of the **exact** type in the question*, unnecessary.

Comment: @Bozho, for example in a `List<Shape>` the first element could be a `Rectangle` while the second was an `Ellipse2D.Double` (which will not fit in a `Rectangle[]`.)

Comment: @finw - true. But the precondition is that the collection is homogenous. I wouldn't do it like that, of course. I warned about an exception there.

Comment: This will work for my purposes, the array elements are also simple types Interger, Float, String etc.. None are generics.

Thanks @Bozho!!!

Answer (score 1):

This method is type safe, and handles some nulls (at least one element must be non-null).

```
public static Object[] toArray(Collection<?> c)
{
  Iterator<?> i = c.iterator();
  for (int idx = 0; i.hasNext(); ++idx) {
    Object o = i.next();
    if (o != null) {
      /* Create an array of the type of the first non-null element. */
      Class<?> type = o.getClass();
      Object[] arr = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(type, c.size());
      arr[idx++] = o;
      while (i.hasNext()) {
        /* Make sure collection is really homogenous with cast() */
        arr[idx++] = type.cast(i.next());
      }
      return arr;
    }
  }
  /* Collection is empty or holds only nulls. */
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unspecified type.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically create an array based on a type known only at runtime (say you're doing reflection or generics) you'll probably want [Array.newInstance](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...))

Comment: you can't downvote and not explain why.  This sounds like the solution.