# How do you iterate over an array that is referenced by Object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a function `get(String)` that returns an `Object` based on an identifying string.

Sometimes, the `Object` returned from `get` is an array. If so, I would like to iterate over each array element and process that element somehow. Something like the following code.

```
 Object object = get(identifier);
 if(object.getClass().isArray())
      processArray(object);

 void processArray(Object array) {
    //For each element in the array, do something
 }
```

My attempted solution of this is something like

```
 void processArray(Object array) {
      Object[] arrayCasted  = (Object[]) array;
      for(Object arrayElement : arrayCasted)
           //Process each element somehow 
 }
```

But this only works for arrays of objects (and not primitive arrays)

```
 Integer[] test1 = {1, 2, 3};
 int[] test2 = {1, 2, 3};
 processArray(test1); //Works
 processArray(test2); //Does not work: ClassCastException
```

Is there anyway to make `processArray` work for all arrays?

Comment: Could you post a code example of your *array referenced by `Object`*, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Also tell the details of the problem *underlying* your question, as you may be asking an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question, and there may be a much cleaner solution to the overall problem than the approach that you're taking.

Comment: "a system that is simulating Java memory" – this seems quite strange, you may want to explain more to get better help.

Comment: Are you asking "if the object I receive is not already an array, I would like to create an array to hold objects of its class, and place my object therein"?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*Java: How can I dynamically create an array of a specified type based on the type of an object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3152290/642706)

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't think so. `object` here seems to have a runtime type of an unknown array type, and OP wants to make its compile time type to be `Object[]`.

Comment: @BasilBourque No, the object is already an array. I need to reference it by `Object[]` instead of `Object`

Comment: @BasilBourque I reworded the question to make it more clear

Comment: @Lindstorm (A) Should that last line be "Is there anyway to make `processArray` work for an array of primitive values as it dose for an array of object references?" ? (B) You should be able to rework that title to succinctly summarize the issue.

Comment: @Lindstrom I deleted my comment about contradicting. On third reading, I found I misunderstood, and edited your Question to help avoid that misreading.

Comment: @BasilBourque (A) If I word it like that, doesn't that suggest that I want to make primitive arrays work with the current implementation (that is, somehow be able to cast a primitive array to `Object[]`)? If so, no because I just in general need to iterate over an array referenced by `Object` and that could use any implementation like the accepted answer (B) I changed the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.lang.reflect.Array` is the key. If you have an `Object` which is actually an array of some type (primitive, String or some custom type, etc.) you can iterate over, print, etc. without knowing its type or doing typecasting, etc.

Typecasting to `Object[]` is not possible since the elelemnts are not of type `Object` but, you can typecast to specific type of array by knowing its component type (`obj.getClass().getComponentType()`). However, `java.lang.reflect.Array` based solution is much cleaner.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class ArrayOfUnknownType {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] i = {1, 2, 3};
        String[] s = {"a", "b", "c"};
        Dog[] d = {new Dog("d"), new Dog("e")};
        process(i);
        process(s);
        process(d);
    }

    private static void process(Object data) {
        System.out.println(data.getClass().getComponentType());
        if(data.getClass().isArray()) {
            int length = Array.getLength(data);
            for(int count =0; count < length; count++ ){
                System.out.println(Array.get(data, count));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Dog {
        public String name;

        public Dog(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Dog{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```